# Access Form VBA if then that loops thru all rows

Tags: loops, ms-access, if-statement, vba

Working on a Ms Access Form, designed to display in data sheet mode to allow the use of viewing and adding multiple rows of data at once.

Once the user inputs their data into the table I have a button they must click before leaving the form. I want the button to validate that either option 1 or 2 is true before running a macro or else a message box prompts the user.

1. Either (Eps OR Clm# is not null)  and that `LPymtDate` is not null.
2. All four fields must have data and not be null (`MdID` or `AdmitDt` or `DischrgDt` or `LPymtDate`)

---

Below is the code i have been using, but it only checks one row of data. Does anyone have suggestions or code that would allow me to validate all rows?

```vb
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Command12_Click()

If Not IsNull([Eps]) Or Not IsNull([Clm#]) And Not IsNull([LPymtDate]) Then
     DoCmd.RunMacro ("CheckingAccts")
ElseIf Not IsNull([MdID]) And Not IsNull([AdmitDt]) And Not IsNull([DischrgDt]) And Not IsNull([LPymtDate]) Then
     DoCmd.RunMacro ("CheckingAccts")
    Else
    MsgBox "Input Required Fields"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Should your macro only run if *all* records pass validation? Or should it run for each validated record?

Comment: The macro should only run if all records pass validation. If one record fails the message box should display a message indicating that the user needs to fill out the required fields.

Comment: Below i was able to to get a code to do my primary objective. There is a problem if the user clicks on the new row and does not enter information. The EOF function act as if this is a row when it is actually an addition run that will not be added.

Answer (score 0):

It would be simpler and also better for the user to validate each rows before saving it - and no button needed.

For this, use the BeforeUpdate event of the form:

```
Cancel = IsNull([Eps] & [Clm#]) Or IsNull([LPymtDate] + [MdID] + [AdmitDt] + [DischrgDt] + [LPymtDate])

If Cancel = True Then
    MsgBox "Please input required fields."
Else
    DoCmd.RunMacro ("CheckingAccts")
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Option Compare Database

Private Sub Command12_Click()
Dim myConnection As ADODB.Connection
Set myConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
Dim myRecordset As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim f As Integer
Dim ans As Integer
Set rst = myRecordset
myRecordset.ActiveConnection = myConnection
myRecordset.Open "Local_Holder_CoverInfo_3_Accounts", , adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic

rst.MoveFirst
Do Until rst.EOF()
If (Not IsNull([Eps]) Or Not IsNull([Clm#])) And Not IsNull([LPymtDate])    Then
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNext
ElseIf Not IsNull([MedID]) And Not IsNull([AdmitDt]) And Not       IsNull([DischrgDt]) And Not IsNull([LPymtDate]) Then
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNext
Else
f = 1
End If
rst.MoveNext
Loop
 If f >= 1 Then
 MsgBox "Input Required Fields"
 Else
 DoCmd.RunMacro ("CheckingAccts")
 End If
 End Sub
```